# Finding $f$ such that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R},f(x+y)f(x-y)=(f(x))^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-equations

Find all the possible continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $|f|=1$ and $$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R},f(x+y)f(x-y)=(f(x))^2.$$
By taking suitable values for $x,y$ we have $f(0)=1,f(2x)=(f(x))^2,$ also $x \to e^{icx},c \in \mathbb{R}$ verifies the above functional equation. Tried to find $f(nx)$ in term of $f(x),$ but unfortunately didn't find anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is $|f| = 1$ valid everywhere?

Comment: yes, everywhere

Comment: To find $y_n:=f(nx)$ use the recursion $y_{n+1}=y_n^2/y_{n-1}$.

Comment: How to solve this recurrence equation?

Comment: Start with $y_0=1$, $y_1=a$, then $y_2=a^2$, etc., you can verify $y_n=a^n$.

Comment: We can write $y_{n+1}/y_n=y_n/y_{n-1}$ and then take the product, so we have $y_{n+1}-f(x)y_n=0,$ which is easy to solve, in other word $y_n=f(nx)=(f(x))^n$ and $f(n)=(f(1))^n$

Comment: Since $|f(1)|=1$ then there exist $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(1)=e^{i\theta},$ so $f(n)=e^{ni\theta},n \in \mathbb{Z},$ from here the work should be easy... (using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$)

Comment: consider accepting answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a=x+y$

$b=x-y$

Because $f(2x)=(f(x))^2$ it is easily seen $f(a)f(b)=f(a+b)$

$f(a)=e^{ig(a)}$

This implies $g(a)+g(b)+k2\pi=g(a+b)$ where $k$ is an integer

define $h(a)=g(a)+k2\pi$

$h(a)+h(b)=g(a)+g(b)+k4\pi$

$h(a)+h(b)=g(a+b)+k2\pi=h(a+b)$

we have $h(a)+h(b)=h(a+b)$ which is Cauchy functional equation with solution $h(a)=ca$ provided $h(a)$ is measurable ($f(a)$ is measurable)

Therefore $f(x)=e^{icx-ik2\pi}=e^{icx}$

Comment: $k$ depends of $x$ (in fact it's equal to $0$)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to observe that $f(x) = \exp({\iota c(x)})$ where $c$ is a real valued funciton with domain same as $f$.

Now plugin the expression to get
$$ 2c(x) = c(x-y) + c(x+y) + 2k\pi $$
Now if we put $y=0$ we can easily see $k=0$ and as you observed the solutions of the equations are $ax+b$

Comment: If only we can prove that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y),$ then it's over

Comment: @Kurt.W.X it is easy to prove that